# Becoming a better iOS and MacOSX Programmer

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I've started using [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) to improve my objective-c coding and have worked through some of the problems. I think it's great so far for wrapping my head around different concepts. Unfortunately, I don't really see any uses in applications I have in mind for iOS and Mac.

I'm going to continue to complete the problems (as I'm able) because I think it's great brain exercise. I've searched but haven't found any sites where there are problems that are more programming related and less math centric.

So far my learning has gone like this:

1. I want to do ***_*___** in my program.
2. Read book about ***_*__**
3. Experiment a bit
4. Watch videos about ***_*__** (I watch the WWDCs and videos like Dr. Larson's Advanced iPhone course)
5. Try to implement new knowledge.

I know both reading related and more general theory books like *'The Pragmatic Programmer'* (started a few days ago - as recommended in stackoverflow question 1711) is going to continue to help me become a better programmer and having stackoverflow is great with the quality of questions and answers provided.

Do you use any other Project Euler-esq sites that are Mac Centric (or at least object oriented) with less math( i.e complete task move on to harder related task)? If not is there another resouce that I'm missing that I should be using to help become better.

I know there are related questions for other programming languages. But I wanted to ask specifically for iOS and Mac development.

---

Here is the article that introduced me to PE
http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/print/2011/06/how-i-failed-failed-and-finally-succeeded-at-learning-how-to-code/239855/

The Project Euler website seems to be down a lot I found a French version for reference to those who don't know what it is http://toprog.fr.nf/ (click on 'Exercices du projet Euler')

Thanks for taking the time to read/respond,

Comment: Hi James; likely your question will be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the [CleanCoder](http://www.cleancoders.com/) videos by "Uncle Bob" Martin to be very useful as far as good coding goes, not Mac specific.

Sure, they are Java based but they are about best practices and with a little effort apply to Objective-C.

Comment: Great.. Always happy to learn.